Delay time in crossbars
I was reading a paper on modeling memristive crossbar arrays. I came across this figure which shows how the delay in the crossbar changes with the crossbar size. The figure on the left is for the case when the memristance is 1kOhm. As you can see, the delay time increases with crossbar size, which makes sense. The figure on the right is for the case when the memristance is 100kOhm. The delay time is more, but for some reason, the delay time gets smaller with larger crossbars, which seems counter intuitive. How is this possible?

